# Node.js: How to get the latest LinkedIn Pulse articles from specific channels?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linkedin-api

I need to get, at the very least, the titles and URLs of the latest 10-20 or more articles in a specific LinkedIn Pulse channel.

[EDIT]
To clarify, my intention isn't to scrape content in a way that violates the Terms of Service. I want to direct users to LinkedIn itself to read the full articles.
[/EDIT]

The LinkedIn API seems to be no help in this matter. I was also unable to find an npm package that would serve this purpose.

So all I can think of is doing a simple HTTP request to, for example, http://www.linkedin.com/pulse/channel/technology, and (via regex) getting the article titles from all the `<span itemprop="headline" class="title">` elements within and getting the URLs to those articles from the `<a>` element that is around them. But I'm not sure how reliable that would be.

Is there a better/simpler/more reliable way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're heading in the right direction here to solve the task from a technical standpoint, as there is no official API for the Pulse Articles.

However, you should consider reading up on the terms of service as it seems questionable whether this would be a violation of the usage terms or not since what you're actually doing is redirecting linkedin content to your own site/app/whatever.

Comment: That isn't quite my intention. I actually want to direct users to LinkedIn itself to read the full articles. Would that be ok?

Comment: I cant answer that for you. Read through the usage terms to make sure you're not violating any of them. Other than that, your way to go at it seems good enough.

Also consider flagging the answer as correct if you think that it helped you.